# How do I use systemd services in /usr/lib/systemd/?

Tags: debian, systemd

How are services installed by the package manager (in `/usr/lib/systemd/`) supposed to be used in Debian (9.5)?

I can see loads of services installed in `/usr/lib/systemd/user`, but these are not available via the normal `systemctl status my-service` command. Am I supposed to manually copy the services I want to use into `/etc/systemd/user/`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Systemd allows you to have a user-specific services for each user in addition to the system-wide services. Those can be managed by regular systemctl command (`stop`, `start`, `status`, `edit`, `enable`, ...) if you add the `--user` flag. If you have for example `/usr/lib/systemd/user/syncthing.service`, the system-wide service manager doesn't know about it, but the one for users does:

```
↪ ls /usr/lib/systemd/user/syncthing.service 
Permissions Size User Date Modified Name
.rw-r--r--   285 root 13 Jun 20:40  /usr/lib/systemd/user/syncthing.service
↪ systemctl status syncthing                                                                                     
Unit syncthing.service could not be found.
↪ systemctl --user status syncthing               
● syncthing.service - Syncthing - Open Source Continuous File Synchronization
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/user/syncthing.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2018-07-24 17:10:22 CEST; 2 weeks 3 days ago
     Docs: man:syncthing(1)
 Main PID: 815 (syncthing)
   CGroup: /user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service/syncthing.service
           └─815 /usr/bin/syncthing -no-browser -no-restart -logflags=0
```

`systemctl status --user` can be used to list all currently active units for the current user.

It's also possible for users to define their own units if they are unable to write to `/usr/lib/systemd/user` or for the administrator to define user units local to the system, by adding them to one of the directories listed for this purpose in [systemd.unit(5)](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html):

- ~/.config/systemd/user/
- /etc/systemd/user/
- $XDG_RUNTIME_DIR/systemd/user/
- ~/.local/share/systemd/user/
- …

Answer (score 2):

Use `systemctl --user status my-service` for user services. User services are also displayed under the `user.slice` of `systemctl status` command. You also need `--user` flag to start/stop/enable/disable these services since they run under a normal user session and don't require root access. Read more at https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd/User